Call wordpress gf (gravity forms) form entries by some filters via rest api
I want to call wordpress gf form entries by specific filters in form fields via rest api. for example i want to get the entries for formID=12 and ip for 1.1.1.1.
To do this, In the postMan, i’ve create new request tab and follow these steps :

Set request method to GET

Set url to : mySite.com/wp-json/gf/v2/entries

Set user and pass in Authorization tab

in body section, i’ve these code :
{
"form_id": 12,
"field_filters": [
{
"key": "ip",
"value": "1.1.1.1"
}
]
}


And click on Send button. But still i’ve received all entries for all forms without any filter!! I think this filtering scenario not working!!
Can anybody help me which how to accomplish this task?
Thanks in advance

"in body section" - GET request do not usually have a body. Plus, you need to provide the field_filters as part of the search parameter value. https://docs.gravityforms.com/searching-and-getting-entries-with-the-rest-api-v2/#search-entries has examples.

Step 4: Go to the Params tab and add the parameters:



Key
Value




form_ids[]
12


search
{"field_filters":[{"key":"ip","value":"1.1.1.1"}]}



You may also try using this endpoint:
/wp-json/gf/v2/forms/12/entries
